# SVN: how to set stage to a sub branch

Tags: svn, ssh, merge, symlink, stage

Hi this is my SVN structure:

```
TRUNK
BRANCH
    --STAGING
TAGS
    --tag1
```

so the goal here is to do all development on sub branch "STAGING" and once it's ready for production  all changes wiill be merged into tag1 and rolled to TRUNK (Production)

How can I set the TRUNK to public_html Production  and staging to Public_html staging

you can see the server folder stucture here

```
 /var/svn/projects/ (trunk, branch and tags are here)

/home/production/public_html <--- producction
/home/staging/public_html <-- staging
```

I would like it when I made a commit to Staging it would go live on staging website.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). This is a continuous build system, but one of the things it does is watch a Subversion URL and take action on a change. For example, you could have a staging branch, and when Jenkins detects the change, it will checkout or export the files on that branch on your server.

Easiest way is to have Jenkins running on your staging server. Jenkins itself uses minimal resources, so it shouldn't be an issue. Setup a job on Jenkins to watch your Staging URL. Setup the job, so the working directory for the job is your staging area's website URL. (This can easily be configured in the job itself). Then when Jenkins sees a change on the staging URL, it will update the staging area.

A better idea is to have two directories. You have the actual staging directory, and another directory that is the next staging area. Jenkins can do an `svn export` to that other directory, then move the old staging directory out of the way, and move the new directory to the staging directory. That way, your staging directory isn't in an inconsistent state as Jenkinds does the update. Even better, Jenkins can take your server up and down as part of moving the new staging area over.

Jenkins, by the way is open source and free to use. It's also easy to setup. It's a single jar file that contains it's own webserver. Just run `java -jar jenkins.war` and it's up and running on your server on port 8080. (Port can be easily changed by passing a parameter). Everything else is pretty self explanatory. Click on the *new job* link and fill out the form.